# Android - recover encrypted images

Tags: aes, android, decryption

I have nearly 0 understanding of encryption, I just want to recover my old photos.

In my old Android phone I used a certain photo-video locking app to encrypt my images. Images were stored on SD card.

I have forgotten the password of app (because 8 months of no use) but I see certain `.config` file, it contains:

```
5Fn7TQ==
 uxyjH3WpAKwKTCDyRdkd9cIPZQkCASZg
```

The app's website says photos are *"encrypted using advanced 128bit AES encryption"*.

So I downloaded AESCrypt but when decrypting I get the error `Error: Bad file header (not aescrypt file or is corrupted? [29, ffffffb6, 35])`. Which is true because it an't encrypted by aescrypt.

So, how do I recover (AES decrypt) my photos.

Also is `.config` file a key file for decrypting images?

**Edit**

I was under the impression that the PIN (the password I had to enter when I launched the app) was protecting access to application's UI **and** had no role in encrypting images because a 5-digit password doesn't seem very secure.

Also I suspect the key is stored on device because the app was able to unlock photos even when device was not connected to the internet.

Comment: What's the name of the photo encryption app ? The app may also use some custom data storage format in addition to AES, which means the files you have aren't raw photos encrypted with AES, but with some metadata attached, so even if you find out/bruteforce the key, you'd still need to make a program to "decode" those files and only get the raw AES-encrypted data.

Comment: Any proper use of encryption will not store the key in a config file. You will need to use the original app as it most likely uses a proprietary structure to encrypt the image file. The only option you have at this point is to try to remember the password used as well designed AES encryption renders the original contents unrecoverable by design unless the exact password is used. Use encryption to protect yourself but expect total data loss unless you have a proper password management system in place to prevent losing/forgetting the password/encryption key.

Comment: @AndréDaniel I used Photo Locker Pro v1.1.0; also I don't think they are using custom data storage because- 1. the app was inexpensive, 2. all files are renamed from `img.jpg` to `img.jpg.pl`, 3. I opened that .pl in text-editor to see binary looking data. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @FiascoLabs I just thought that contents of file look like some hash/password. I do have the .apk of that app in my back-up, it opens with 7z archive manager - which has `META-INF` folder containing `HANDYAPP.RSA`, `HANDYAPP.SF` & `MANIFEST.MF` does this help?

Comment: What OS are you trying to do this in?  I assume Android refers to your old phone.  Are you working with the SD card on a computer?

Answer (score 1):

Any proper use of encryption will not store the key in a config file. While a hash might be stored, it's one way, so knowing the hash will not allow for recovery of the password, only that the entered password's hash matches the stored hash, and therefore the proper password was entered.

You will need to use the original app as it most likely uses a proprietary structure to encrypt the image file. The only option you have at this point is to try to remember the password used as well designed AES encryption renders the original contents unrecoverable by design unless the exact password is used.

Use encryption to protect yourself but expect total data loss unless you have a proper password management system in place to prevent losing/forgetting the password/encryption key.

Since this is Photo Locker Pro, produced by Handy Apps, perusing their Google Store and online website FAQ delivers the following information.

1. With the optional PIN recovery feature, you won't lose your precious files even if you forgot your PIN code.
2. The recovery email address is not an username to restore data. It is only used to retrieve your PIN in the event that you have forgotten it.

It's time to contact their support desk (support at handy-apps.com) and see if they can help you finish the recovery process.

Comment: I do realize that - but the helpdesk is not replying, maybe because of 8 months of dormancy or probably they are hell bent on making me re-buy the software.

Comment: Then you will have to brute force it, ie try all number combinations that it might have been. They mention PIN which most people use only 4 numbers for. AES is built secure and will only deencrypt when you enter the right pass phrase.

Comment: any suggestion because I can't try 10^5 permutations manually - that too on a touchscreen :P. Thanks, any help will be much appreciated.